# Get center of an imported game object from 3D modeling software

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, physics

I am new here and I am a Unity beginner. For my game I imported a ring which I created in a 3 modeling software. Now I would like to find out the center of that ring. Moreover I would like to follow the position of the center of that ring and put this in a vector. Please some help. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Edit:

Thank you for your answers and sorry that I was not specific enough. In order to get a clearer idea of what I like to try I give you some informations of what I would like to do. I would create a "hot wire game" with a sine wave moving wire which has to followed with a ring. The aim of this game would be that the center of the ring has to be on the wire. So if the player was not precise enough there would be an error (desired position which would be the moving wire - actual position which would be the center of the ring).

Here  link of what I would like to have at the end:

https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/hot-wire-heisser-draht/id941657787?mt=8

https://processing.org/examples/sinewave.html

So far I have the code for the moving sine wave made by multiple spheres. Here the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SineWaveSpheres : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject plotPointObject;  public int numberOfPoints= 100;
    private float animSpeed =1.0f;  public float scaleInputRange = 8*Mathf.PI; // scale number from [0 to 99] to [0 to 2Pi] //Zahl vor Mathf, Anzahl Bön
    public float scaleResult = 2.5f; // Y Achse Range
    public bool animate = true;
    public Vector3 posSphere;
    GameObject[] plotPoints;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (plotPointObject == null) //if user did not fill in a game object to use for the plot points
            plotPointObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere); //create a sphere

        //add Material to the spheres , load material in the folder Resources/Materials
        Material myMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials/green", typeof(Material)) as Material;
        plotPointObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = myMaterial;

        //change the scale of the spheres 
        plotPointObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.5f ;

        plotPoints = new GameObject[numberOfPoints]; //creat an array of 100 points.
        //plotPointObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material =Material.Load("blue") as Material

        //plotPointObject.transform.localScale -= new Vector3 (0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F); //neu: change the scale of the spheres

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
        {
            plotPoints[i] = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(plotPointObject, new Vector3(i - (numberOfPoints/2), 0, 0), Quaternion.identity); //this specifies what object to create, where to place it and how to orient it
        }       //we now have an array of 100 points- your should see them in the hierarchy when you hit play

        plotPointObject.SetActive(false); //hide the original
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) 
        {
            float functionXvalue = i * scaleInputRange / numberOfPoints; // scale number from [0 to 99] to [0 to 2Pi]
            if (animate) {
                functionXvalue += Time.time * animSpeed;
            }

            plotPoints[i].transform.position = new Vector3(i - (numberOfPoints/2), ComputeFunction(functionXvalue) * scaleResult, 0); 

            // put the position information of sphere clone 50 in a vector3 named posSphere posSphere = plotPoints [50].transform.position;
        }
        //print position of sphere 50 in console        //print (posSphere);
    }

    float ComputeFunction(float x)
    {
        return Mathf.Sin(x);
    }
}
```

And as I said I have this ring from a 3D modeling software. It seems that the center of the ring is on the origin (0,0,0). Therefore my though was I could just do the following to calculate the error:

```
error=posSphere-posRing
```

where posSphere I would take from the SineWave Script above and posRing I would take from the Ring Script

```
posRing=transform.position;
```

Are I am wrong?

My questions:

1. Where (in which script) I have to do this calculation? And in which function (LateUpdate,FixedUpdate)?
2. I tried to access the vector posSphere within the Ring script by

   ```
   error=SineWaveSpheres.posSpheres-posRing;
   ```

   where SineWaveSpheres is the class of the sine wave moving spheres script. Is this logic correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what code you've tried and where you're stuck. As written, your question is broad.

Comment: note that the 3D modelling program will "set" the center.  this is a tricky issue - often you have to "reset" it if that makes sense, because it's not where you want it to be!  when you drop it in to Unity, THE POSITION OF THAT GAME OBJECT is indeed the "center" so marked in the modelling software

Comment: I tried now to better explain what I like to do in my game... I am just not sure if I can use this 3D model of the ring for my game or if I have to create a torus with mesh which would be too complex for me to do...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a lot to explain. First of all, you got a nice code there but it has nothing to do with your problem, am I right? But anyways, here are the answers IMHO

1. Since this script is just to create the Sine Wave, you should create another script for the Ring stuff ( movement, logic, math, etc ). There you can do the calculation, in the Update function ( LateUpdate it's used when you want to override animated transforms ; FixedUpdate it's used when you are referencing GameObjects affected by physics ). Anyway I would highly recomend you to just avoid doing the vector correction and just modificate the center of the ring in your 3D suite.
2. That won't work mostly because your are accessing a non-static member through the class itself ; you must use an instance of the class instead. Something like

   var sineWaveSpheres = someGameObject.GetComponent <SineWaveSpheres> ();

The thing is I don't recomend you to check if player failed this way, I mean, you can just do a collision check:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "the name of the sine wave spehere gameobject")
    {
        //game over, do stuff
    }
}
```

This code must be added to a script attached to the ring GameObject.

This way you don't have to worry about the center of the ring and vector math stuff. The only thing to keep in mind is that you do have to add a collider to both the ring and the sphere prefab to be instantinated.

That's pretty much all I think, hope it helps! ^^